# UWP app failing windows app certification kit tests: Windows Runtime metadata validation

Tags: uwp

It's a cppwinrt UWP app targeting Windows-10 platform, I am trying to run WACK test for my app and I am seeing this error:

**Supported API test**

*FAILED*

Supported APIs

*Error Found:* The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

```
API __CxxFrameHandler4 in vcruntime140_1_app.dll is not supported for this application type. DocViewerApp.exe calls this API.
```

*Impact if not fixed:* Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.
*How to fix:* Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information:
Alternatives to Windows APIs in Microsoft Store apps.

......

......

**Windows Runtime metadata validation**

*FAILED*

Type Location

*Error Found:* The type location test detected the following errors:

```
The types in the Windows.AI.MachineLearning namespace are located in file Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd that does not match the namespace.
The types in the Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview namespace are located in file Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview.MachineLearningPreviewContract.winmd that does not match the namespace.
The types in the Windows.ApplicationModel.Background namespace are located in file Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.CallsBackgroundContract.winmd that does not match the namespace.
............
............
```

*Impact if not fixed:* Microsoft store doesn't allow apps that don't pass Windows Runtime Metadata Validation.
*How to fix:* Please ensure that the metadata for all Windows Runtime types is located in the winmd file that has the longest namespace-matching name in the app package.

*FAILED*

Type name correctness

*Error Found:* The type name correctness test detected the following errors:

```
The Windows.AI.MachineLearning.LearningModelDeviceKind type in the Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd file is in the Windows namespace.
The Windows.AI.MachineLearning.LearningModelFeatureKind type in the Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd file is in the Windows namespace.
............
............
```

*Impact if not fixed:* Microsoft store doesn't allow apps that don't pass Windows Runtime Metadata Validation.
*How to fix:* Please ensure there are no Windows Runtime types in the global namespace or in the Windows top-level namespace.

*FAILED*
General metadata correctness
*Error Found:* The general metadata correctness test detected the following errors:

```
The type Windows.Foundation.IAsyncInfo in file Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd has the same GUID as the following types: Windows.Foundation.IAsyncInfo. All GUIDs must be unique.
The type Windows.Devices.SmartCards.ISmartCardCryptogramStorageKeyInfo2 in file Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract.winmd has the same GUID as the following types: Windows.Devices.SmartCards.ISmartCardCryptogramStorageKeyInfo2. All GUIDs must be unique.
```

---

There are no errors before visual studio 16.6.3.
The visual studio guys identified this issue as a Windows issue.

Does anyone have the same problem? How to deal with it?

Comment: If you are running the local WACK test, I'd suggest you upload your package to the store and submit. There will be another online WACK test and you could take the online test results as the standard.

Comment: There is no "Supported API test" error in the online WACK test result . "Windows Runtime metadata validation" errors are always shown  in both online/offline test results.

Comment: Do you still remember what have you changed in your project since last submission? What's the target version and min version of your app?

Comment: Upgrading visual studio to 16.6.3, upgrading cppwinrt to 2.0.200615.7. Platform target version=10.0.19041.0 and min version= 10.0.18362.0

Comment: So you just changed the configure and the code is still the same? Then the issue comes? It looks like indeed an issue about the Visual Studio compiler. Have you tried to downgrade the version of cppwinrt nuget package and run the test again? Will the issue still happen?

Comment: Downgrade the version of cppwinrt nuget package to 2.0.200602.3, there are no  "Windows Runtime metadata validation" any more. Thank you very much.

Comment: downgrade worked. Thank you.